# Second foreach in the foreach loop returns bool(false) though array is present

Tags: php, foreach

In my code below the data is extracted correctly for the first `foreach ($booklist as $post)`, but doesn't return anything for 2nd `foreach ($authorlist as $post)` although selected one present inside the 2nd `foreach`. I still get the error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for line `foreach ($authorlist as $post)`...

However the 2nd `foreach` returns data correctly as soon as I remove the first `foreach` loop.

Below is my code

```
<?php

$all= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'books', 'numberposts' => -1,));

foreach ( $all as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

    if (!empty($post))
    {
     $booklink = array();

     $booklist = get_field('booklist'); 
               foreach ($booklist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                    if (!empty($post))
                        {
                        $booklink[] = strip_tags(get_field('booklink',$post));                                       
                        }
                endforeach;
                wp_reset_postdata();
     echo $booklink[0];  

     $authorname = array();

     $authorlist = get_field('authorlist'); 
               foreach ($authorlist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                    if (!empty($post))
                        {
                        $authorname[] = strip_tags(get_field('authorname',$post));                                       
                        }
                endforeach;
                wp_reset_postdata();
echo $authorname[0]; 

    }
endforeach;
?>
```

I did `var_dump($authorlist)` and it returns `bool(false)` as long as `foreach ($booklist as $post)`  loop is present. The moment I remove that loop then the dump shows the data of the `authorlist` correctly. How to get both the loops working together?

You can see the output [here](http://myproject.byethost7.com/wp/?page_id=6)

Comment: Please don't double posts. I have already answered your question on WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

you set `$post` as row for all loops : `foreach ( $all as $post )`  and `foreach ($booklist as $post)` and  `foreach ($authorlist as $post)`. so `$post` will change in all foreaches. change the variables name.